# Panel in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

While I am using pandas Panel, it shows that Panel function takes no argument...

My code -

```
data = {'Item1' : pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3)), 'Item2' : pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2))}
panel = pd.Panel(data)
panel
```

The output -

```
TypeError: Panel() takes no arguments
```

Then, I try

```
dir(pandas)
```

In that, Panel function is not in the pandas-dir()

pandas version (v 0.25.1)

But This code -

```
p = pd.Panel()
p
```

output -

```
<pandas.__getattr__.<locals>.Panel at 0xec5cfc8>
```

After that, I checked

```
dir(pandas.__getattr__)
```

The panel is not present in this function too

Any suggestion , Thank you

Comment: FYI - pandas webpage states that panel is deprecated: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Panel.html

Comment: This is s standard pandas question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2):

The `Panel` object is deprecated and all its functionality was [removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/panel.html) in pandas 0.25.

You can use the standard `DataFrame` with [multi-level index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing) instead for representing 3-dimensional (or even higher-dimensional) data sets.